# Java ImageIO-ext TIF File Corrupt when Read

Tags: java, tiff, javax.imageio, jai

I am attempting to display a `.tif` in Java using a minimal number of additional libraries:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import javax.media.jai.widget.*;
import it.geosolutions.imageio.utilities.*;
import it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.*;
import com.sun.media.imageioimpl.common.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File f = new File("image.tif");  
        BufferedImage tif = ImageIO.read(f);  
        ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon(tif);  
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        JLabel label = new JLabel(ic);  
        frame.add(label);  
        frame.setVisible(true);  
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The libraries I'm using are:

```
 jai-core-1.1.3.jar
 jai-imageio-1.1.jar
 imageio-ext-tiff.1.1.3.jar
 imageio-ext-utilities.1.1.3.jar
```

From here: http://java.net/projects/imageio-ext (Downloads link on right side)

However, the displayed image is:
[image: corrupted-tif]
which is decidedly **not** the original image.  Nor are any errors being thrown that I know of.  Furthermore, the original image is fine, and doesn't change.

However, the original code is small.  I don't actually use the `imageio-ext` imports, but the program will fail without them.  I also haven't used `imageio-ext` before either.

Please help! I need to be able to use `.tif` images in Java without installing software.

Comment: What is the error? Could you put the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the most-recent version of [`Apache-Commons Imaging`](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/) (formerly Sanselan).  `Imaging` offers out of the box support for TIFF files (I had as little bit of trouble at first, but that was solved by switching from the older Sanselan to the newer Commons Imaging).

There was a little bit of functionality I had to reverse-engineer myself (loading a single sub-TIFF at a specified width while maintaining aspect ratio):

```
/**
 * Load a scaled sub-TIFF image.  Loads nth sub-image and scales to given width; preserves aspect ratio.
 * 
 * @param fileName String filename
 * @param index Index of sub-TIFF; will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if sub-image doesn't exist
 * @param w Desired width of image; height will scale
 * @return Image (BufferedImage)
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws ImageReadException
 */
public static Image loadScaledSubTIFF(String fileName, int index, int w) throws IOException, ImageReadException {
    File imageFile = new File(fileName);
    ByteSourceFile bsf = new ByteSourceFile(imageFile);
    FormatCompliance formatCompliance = FormatCompliance.getDefault();
    TiffReader tiffReader = new TiffReader(true);
    TiffContents contents = tiffReader.readDirectories(bsf, true, formatCompliance);
    TiffDirectory td = contents.directories.get(index);
    Image bi = td.getTiffImage(tiffReader.getByteOrder(), null);
    Object width = td.getFieldValue(new TagInfo("", 256, TiffFieldTypeConstants.FIELD_TYPE_SHORT) {/**/});
    Object height = td.getFieldValue(new TagInfo("", 257, TiffFieldTypeConstants.FIELD_TYPE_SHORT) {/**/});
    int newWidth = w;
    int newHeight = (int) ((newWidth * ((Number)height).doubleValue()) / (((Number)width).doubleValue()));

    bi = bi.getScaledInstance(w, newHeight, java.awt.Image.SCALE_FAST);
    height = null;
    width = null;
    td = null;
    contents = null;
    tiffReader = null;
    formatCompliance = null;
    bsf = null;
    return bi;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already use all JAI/ImageIO libraries, you might want to try the following (which works fine for me):

```
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.FileSeekableStream;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageCodec;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageDecoder;

// This function is minimal, you should add exceptions and error handling
public RenderedImage read(String filename)
    FileSeekableStream fss = new FileSeekableStream(filename);
    ImageDecoder decoder = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", fss, null);
    RenderedImage image = decoder.decodeAsRenderedImage()
    fss.close();
    return image;
}
```

If you need a `BufferedImage` instead of a `RenderedImage`, the only solution I found is to use this function:

```
public static BufferedImage Rendered2Buffered(RenderedImage image) {
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getSampleModel().getDataType());
    bi.setData(image.getData());
    return bi;
}
```

Be careful though, the `image.getSampleModel().getDataType()` usually returns a `BufferedImage.TYPE_CUSTOM`, which makes it impossible for the `BufferedImage` to be created! In my case I had to "guess" the type according to the sample size returned by `image.getSampleModel().getSampleSize(0)` (because I know the image format I'm working with).
If you know a better way to transform a `RenderedImage` to a `BufferedImage`, please enlighten me :)

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in thinking that you need the JAI libraries to decode and use TIFF files, but even though you've imported them, you aren't actually using them!

[Here is a short tutorial](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai1_0_1guide-unc/Examples.doc.html) showing how you to create a TIFFDecodeParam object (from the JAI library), and then use that to decode (and display) a TIFF image.

You might also find the [JAI API Library](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/index.html) useful too.

Comment: The tutorial you link to uses different libraries instead of `ImageIO-ext`  Where are these libraries?  I have to admit to searching for the JAI libraries for a while before finding the `ImageIO-ext` lib.

Comment: Also, this is an interesting analysis, because exceptions are thrown in the program above when the imports are not included, but no exceptions are thrown when they are there...

Comment: The libraries you need are `javax.media.jai.*` and `com.sun.media.jai.codec.*`. As far as I'm aware, both of these are included with an install of the (Sun) JDK.
To be honest, I didn't notice that you were also linking to the `imageio-ext` libraries. I've never come across these before, which is why I thought that you weren't using the JAI libraries.

Comment: It appears that the `ImageIO-ext` libraries "enhance" the functionality of the built-in ImageIO. If you don't include these libraries, then the default ImageIO (used in your code) doesn't support TIFF and will throw an invalid file format exception (an `IOException`, I believe).

Comment: Interesting...I have the `javax.media.jai.*;` package, and the `com.sun.media.jai.*;` package, but I don't have the `com.sun.media.jai.codec.*;` packages...could this be a later addition to the JDK (I forgot to mention I'm bound to 1.5)?

Comment: Hmmm, that is interesting... According to [this](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/iio.html), "The Java Image I/O API is part of the JavaTM 2 Platform, Standard Edition, version 1.4 (J2SE1.4)". You can still download and install the JAI library yourself though, from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7661-jai-1.1.1-src-oth-JPR).

Comment: :( unfortunately the requirements for the project I'm on really frown on software installs.  Do you by chance know of a .jar-only TIFF library?  Or a way to use JAI just through Java, without running an installer?

Comment: You can download a .jar version of the JAI from that download page I linked above. Look for the "`Windows Auto-Installation`" download.

Comment: No sign of `com.sun.media.jai.codec.*;` in that jar file... I'll keep looking though...